# getting started with websocket api implementation

Tags: websocket

I want to create a very small application using java to understand about the websocket. The application is going to be like a stock market ticker app (very basic level) and I wnat to use tomcat

So can some one guide me on how to use the websocket API both on the server side (servlet) as well as on the client side (JS) without relying on the frameworks like JWebsoket etc

Thanks

Comment: I tried to install Jwebsocket and as an exe its works fine and am able to see the examples but when I tried to write my own server side impl of websocket, its pain and am having lot of issues in deploying the war file itself into tomcat

Comment: The wikipedia page on websocket has a good introduction and a few good links, to the RFC in particular (6455). Look at what the socket-io guys did (which also explains why websockets do not work anywhere). Example of commercial applications, check kaazing.

Comment: @BGR: i have gone thro the wikipedia page of websockets and the RFC page also... its good but I need some guidance on getting this thing to make good in server side esp using java so I am looking for some pointers for the websockets API and NOT websockets in general

Comment: You might want to have a look at Jetty. Mature WS server. Then there is a JSR for WebSocket API being cooked up.

Comment: @siva an API without a framework mmmmhhh...

Comment: @BGR: with framework also am ok but the problem is I  dont know how to create a server side app (in this case stock market ticket app) along with websocket APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be referred for getting started with websocket apis 
http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/